# Plot for every n to compare the result

Tags: plotting

if I want to plot this cod for every n how should I try it? if I use n as example equal to 4 I want a plot with n=1 n=2 n=3 n=4
Any idea?

```
 Remove["Global`*"]
n = 6;
y = Sum[x^i*a[i], {i, 2, n}];
th = D[y, x];
M = EI*D[y, {x, 2}];
V = EI*D[y, {x, 3}];
PE = EI/2*Integrate[D[y, {x, 2}]^2, {x, 0, L}] + P*(y /. x -> L);
Eq = Table[D[PE, a[i]], {i, 1, n}];
sol = Solve[Eq == 0, Array[a, n]]
Y = y /. sol
th /. sol
Eq /. sol;
m = FullSimplify[M /. sol[[1]]]
v = FullSimplify[V /. sol[[1]]]
EI = 100;
P = 1;
L = 10;

Plot[{m}, {x, 0, L}, AxesLabel -> {"x (m)", "M (N.m.)"}, 
 PlotLegends -> {Style[" M", Bold, 12]}]
Plot[{v}, {x, 0, L}, AxesLabel -> {"x (m)", "V (N/m^2.)"}, 
 PlotLegends -> {Style[" V", Bold, 12]}]
Plot[{Y}, {x, 0, L}, AxesLabel -> {"x (m)", "Y (m)"}, 
 PlotLegends -> {Style[" Y", Bold, 12]}]
```

Example: if we change then we get different answers for the same problem I just don't want to do it manually. I want to calculate it for every i from 1 to n and plot it in the same plot for M which is a momentum y which is deformation and V is shear. it is really easy in other program languages like python but I have to use Matematica because I have to do it analytically.

```
(*Second Degree*)
Clear[y, x, M, V, th, EI, PE]
y = a2*x^2
th = D[y, x];
M = EI*D[y, {x, 2}];
V = EI*D[y, {x, 3}];
PE = EI/2*Integrate[D[y, {x, 2}]^2, {x, 0, L}] + P*(y /. x -> L);
Eq2 = D[PE, a2];
Sol = Solve[{Eq2 == 0}, {a2}]
y = y /. Sol[[1]]
th /. Sol[[1]]
FullSimplify[M /. Sol[[1]]]
FullSimplify[V /. Sol[[1]]]
(*Third Degree*)
Clear[y, x, M, V, th, EI, PE]
y = a3*x^3 + a2*x^2
th = D[y, x];
M = EI*D[y, {x, 2}];
V = EI*D[y, {x, 3}];
PE = EI/2*Integrate[D[y, {x, 2}]^2, {x, 0, L}] + P*(y /. x -> L);
Eq1 = D[PE, a3];
Eq2 = D[PE, a2];
Sol = Solve[{Eq1 == 0, Eq2 == 0}, {a3, a2}]
y = y /. Sol[[1]]
th /. Sol[[1]]
FullSimplify[M /. Sol[[1]]]
FullSimplify[V /. Sol[[1]]]
(*Fourth Degree*)
Clear[y, x, M, V, th, EI, PE]
y = a4*x^4 + a3*x^3 + a2*x^2
th = D[y, x];
M = EI*D[y, {x, 2}];
V = EI*D[y, {x, 3}];
PE = EI/2*Integrate[D[y, {x, 2}]^2, {x, 0, L}] + P*(y /. x -> L);
Eq1 = D[PE, a3];
Eq2 = D[PE, a2];
Eq3 = D[PE, a4];
Sol = Solve[{Eq1 == 0, Eq2 == 0, Eq3 == 0}, {a3, a2, a4}]
y = y /. Sol[[1]]
th /. Sol[[1]]
FullSimplify[M /. Sol[[1]]]
FullSimplify[V /. Sol[[1]]]
```

Comment: Maybe you wanted `m = FullSimplify[M /. sol[[1]]]` and `Plot[{m, -100, 100}, {x, 0, L},AxesLabel -> {"x (m)", "M (N.m.)"},  PlotLegends -> {Style[" M", Bold, 12]}]` ?

Comment: JUP thanks but if I want to get this plot for each n what should I do?

Comment: But how does `M` depend on `n`? From your code it is not clear. Also, there are some pieces of code not really relevant for the question. Maybe make a minimal example.

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2059701).

Comment: @yarchik its the order of the polynomial, For  ritz method, in this case, there is no real difference between answers but higher order of polynomial lead to more accurate ansewer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Remove["Global`*"]
n = 4;
y = Sum[x^i*a[i], {i, 2, n}];
th = D[y, x];
M = EI*D[y, {x, 2}];
V = EI*D[y, {x, 3}];
PE = EI/2*Integrate[D[y, {x, 2}]^2, {x, 0, L}] + P*(y /. x -> L);
Eq = Table[D[PE, a[i]], {i, 1, n}];
sol = Reduce[Eq == 0 && L > 0 && P > 0 && Re[EI] > 0, Array[a, n], 
  Reals]
sol[[1]]
sol[[2]]
sol[[3]]
sol[[4]]
(*sol=Solve[Eq\[Equal]0,Array[a,n]]*)

ysol[x_] := sol[[4, 2]] x^2 - sol[[5, 2]] x^3 + sol[[6, 2]] x^4
ysol[x]
D[ysol[x], x]
Table[D[EI/2*Integrate[D[ysol[x], {x, 2}]^2, {x, 0, L}] + 
   P*(ysol[x] /. x -> L), sol[3 + i]], {i, 1, n}]
M = FullSimplify[EI*D[ysol[x], {x, 2}]]
FullSimplify[EI*D[ysol, {x, 3}]]
EI = 100;
P = 1;
L = 10;
Plot[{M, -100, 100}, {x, 0, L}, AxesLabel -> {"x (m)", "M (N.m.)"}, 
 PlotLegends -> {Style[" M", Bold, 12]}]
```

---

EI > 0 && L > 0 && P > 0 && a[2] == -((L P)/(2 EI)) &&
a[3] == (-5 L P - 12 EI a[2])/(6 EI L) &&
a[4] == (-L^2 P - 4 EI L a[2] - 6 EI L^2 a[3])/(8 EI L^3)

---

-((L P x^2)/(2 EI)) - (x^3 (-5 L P - 12 EI a[2]))/(6 EI L) + (
x^4 (-L^2 P - 4 EI L a[2] - 6 EI L^2 a[3]))/(8 EI L^3)

---

-((L P x)/EI) - (x^2 (-5 L P - 12 EI a[2]))/(2 EI L) + (
x^3 (-L^2 P - 4 EI L a[2] - 6 EI L^2 a[3]))/(2 EI L^3)

---

{0, 0, 0, 0}

---

-L P + 5 P x - (6 EI x^2 a[2])/L^2 - (
3 x (P x - 8 EI a[2] + 6 EI x a[3]))/(2 L)

---

0

---

[image: Plot]

This is not a problem suitable for `Solve`.

Comment: I just edited the original post for a better understanding, thanx for your answer I will try it again.